# OPEN FDA beta - 2 Letter Codes for device attribute - "manufacturer_country"

Tags: openfda

what are the 2 letter codes for the device attribute - "manufacturer_country" based on?  are these fips codes or so-3166 alpha 2 codes or some other coding scheme?  it seems there are multiple codes referencing the same country (e.g. ch / sz for switzerland).

Comment: How about a link to the data you're talking about?